# VSC doesn't show import suggestion from django

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-import, pylance

I wonder why my Visual studio code doesn't show me import suggestion from Django framework but show suggestions from other packages?

[image: Screen]

I have installed Pylance and already add this line in `settings.json`:

```
"python.languageServer": "Default"
```

Anyone have some advice how add this functionality?

Comment: The same issue I faced, I'm looking for a solution, did you get it working ?

Comment: Yes, I solved the problem.
I edited  settings.json (ctrl+shit+p -> Open Settings (JSON) ) by adding at the end my path to site-packages folder from my python environment and "sources"
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "./sources",
    "C:\\Users\\User\\...\\site-packages",
  ],

Answer (score 1):

> Note: I disabled all VS Code extensions, installed the official Python extension
> and Pylance extension.

This is how I got Django import suggestions.

```
├── .vscode
│   └── settings.json
├── mysite
│   └── ...
└── manage.py
```

Add this to `.vscode/settings.json`.

```
{
    "python.analysis.packageIndexDepths": [
        { "name": "", "depth": 8, "includeAllSymbols": true }
    ]
}
```

The depth needs to be greater than `8` in my case but your mileage may vary.

The `settings.json` is borrowed from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3281#issuecomment-1440443650)

[image]